# How do I find the intersection of two arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, intersection

Trying to find the **intersection of 2 arrays** `a` and `b` and store it into a new array `c`.

Expected result: array **c** with values: `3, 10, 4, 8`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {3, 10, 4, 2, 8};
    int[] b = {10, 4, 12, 3, 23, 1, 8};
    int[] c;
    int i = 0;
    for (int f = 0; f < a.length; f++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
            if (a[f] == b[k]) {
                //here should be a line that stores equal values of 2 arrays(a,b) into array c
            }
          }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < c.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this isn't homework that strictly requires array ickies, see the `Set` interface - it's slightly more tricky if oder maintenance is required, but not much.

Comment: you have the code right there, and an i(ndex) that starts at 0 that isn't being used.

Comment: check this link http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be an easy way to do.

```
int a[] = {3, 10, 4, 2, 8};
int[] b = {10, 4, 12, 3, 23, 1, 8};
List<Integer> aList =  Arrays.asList(a);
List<Integer> bList =  Arrays.asList(b);
aList.retainAll(bList);
System.out.println(" a intersection b "+aList);
int[] c = aList.toArray(new int[0]);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. For one, because of `Arrays.asList` returning a `List<int[]`. Two, `toArray` can never receive an array of a primitive type. Generics don't work with primitives.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {3, 10, 4, 2, 8};
        int[] b = {10, 4, 12, 3, 23, 1, 8};
        int[] c = new int[(int)Math.min(a.length, b.length)];
        int i=0;
         for(int f=0;f<a.length;f++){
              for(int k=0;k<b.length;k++){
                    if(a[f]==b[k]){
                    c[i] = a[f];
                    i++;
            }
          }
        }
        for (int x=0; x<i; x++){
           System.out.println(c[x]);
        }
       }
  }
```

Hope it helps. Or if you have time complexity issue then try [Java Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 0):

if permitted use ArrayList for c, its growable array

```
ArrayList c = new ArrayList();
.
.
.
.
.
c.add(a[f]);
```

also if permitted to sort arrays, i recommend you to sort smaller array and then iterate over larger array and binary search in smaller array.

Comment: I think you should clarify that this is a good solution if it is allowed. For all we know, there may be some restrictions on the OP's project that don't allow using ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure this would do something I need but I'm not familiar with ArrayLists yet.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to allocate space for your array:

```
int[] c = new int[SOME_SIZE];
```

The hard part is figuring out how much `SOME_SIZE` should be. Since you are calculating an intersection, the most it can be is the size of the smallest of `a` and `b`.

Finally, to assign an element in the array, you just do

```
c[idx] = a[f]
```

Now you need to keep track of where `idx` goes. I suggest starting with `idx = 0` and incrementing it each time you find a new element to add to `c`.

Comment: That's confusing for a beginner. But thank you :)

Comment: @AlexandrMelnik If you are confused, I suggest that you try to write a program which copies one array to another. If you still have problems with using arrays in this simpler program, then you should read more about them and come back with some specific questions for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a help of temporary variable (but this is basically reinventing the wheel, if you are not required to do so) -

```
int[] c = new int[0];
//...
    if(a[f] == b[k]) { 
        int[] temp = c;
        c = new int[c.length + 1];
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
            c[i] = temp[i];
        }
        c[c.length - 1] = a[f];
    }
//...
```

Comment: as long as both ways are right I can prefer any of them :)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use **org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] array2 = {3, 4, 5};
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(array1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(array2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<?> intersection = (List<?>) CollectionUtils.intersection(list1, list2);

    System.out.println(intersection); // Prints: [3]
}
```