# I want to Separate similar value from array In java

Tags: java, arrays

See my below code and please let me know the correction.
i have written my Expected result.. please help me.

```
    try
{
    List<String> assocIds= new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> actionids= new ArrayList<String>();
    assocIds.add("1");
    assocIds.add("2");
    assocIds.add("3");
    assocIds.add("5");

    actionids.add("2");
    actionids.add("3");
    actionids.add("7");
    actionids.add("4");
    actionids.add("6");


    List<String> matchFromFirstArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> notMatchFromFisrtArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> notMatchFromSecondArray= new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int j=0;j<assocIds.size();j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<actionids.size();i++)
        {
            if(assocIds.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase(actionids.get(i)))
            {
                matchFromFirstArray.add(assocIds.get(j));

            }else
            {
                notMatchFromFisrtArray.add(assocIds.get(j));
                notMatchFromSecondArray.add(actionids.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("match from first array : "+matchFromFirstArray.toString());
    System.out.println("not match from fisrt array : "+notMatchFromFisrtArray.toString());
    System.out.println("unmatch form second array : "+notMatchFromSecondArray.toString());


}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error :"+e);
}
}
```

`My Expected Result:`

match from first array : [2, 3]

not match from fisrt array : [1, 5]

unmatch form second array : [7, 4, 6]

`My OUTPUT:`

match from first array : [2, 3]

not match from fisrt array : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

unmatch form second array : [2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6]

Comment: Have you tried doing any debugging yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> matchFromFirstArray= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> notMatchFromFisrtArray= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> notMatchFromSecondArray= new ArrayList<String>();

matchFromFirstArray.addAll(assocIds);
matchFromFirstArray.retainAll(actionids); // retains all matching elements


notMatchFromFisrtArray.addAll(assocIds);
notMatchFromFisrtArray.removeAll(matchFromFirstArray); // retains all not matching elements from first array



notMatchFromSecondArray.addAll(actionids);
notMatchFromSecondArray.removeAll(matchFromFirstArray); // retains all not matching elements from second array
```