# Finding intersection of two sorted arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
    public class intersect {
  public static void find(int[] a, int[] b, int[] acc) 
  {
    int position = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k<b.length; k++) {
        if (a[j] == b[k]) {          
          acc[position] = b[k];
          position++;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(acc));
  }

public static void main (String[] s)
{
  int[] acc = new int[2];
  int[] a = {1,2,3};
  int[] b = {2,3,4};
  find(a, b, acc);
}
}
```

I have written the above code to solve the problem.
But if you see, the function is very limited because I have to change the length of the acc every time. That means I have to know how many elements are  intersecting. In this case, the array {1,2,3} and {2,3,4} have {2,3} in common, so the length of the acc would be 2.

I am sure there are millions of ways of tackling this problem, but I cannot seem to think of a way of fixing this.

Please help!

Comment: You can populate your answer in an ArrayList, and then convert it into an array. Google `java ArrayList`

Comment: A resizable container is appropriate for problems like this; I would probably go with [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). If you use the former, I recommend setting the default size of the smaller of the two arrays.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use one of the implementation of [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which are intended to be used for set-related problems like this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the intersection of two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your professor wants you to use arrays, you can use the following method:

```
public static int[] resize(int[] arr)
{
    int len = arr.length;
    int[] copy = new int[len+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

This will increase the size of the array by 1. You can use that instead. By the way, you're not using the fact that they're sorted in your `find()` method. What you should do is this:

```
public static void find(int[] a, int[] b, int[] acc)
{
    int a_index = 0, b_index = 0, acc_index = -1;
    int a_element, b_element;
    while (a_index < a.length && b_index < b.length)
    {
        a_element = a[a_index]; b_element = b[b_index];
        if (a_element == b_element)
        {
            acc = resize(acc);
            acc[++acc_index] = a_element;
            a_index++; b_index++;
        } else if (b_element < a_element) {
            b_index++;
        } else {
            a_index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(acc));
}
```

This method is more efficient now. [Working example](http://ideone.com/0CJ925).

Comment: Hm... If I were to take advantage of the sorted array, should I add this? 

        if (a[j] > b[k]) {
          break;
        }

I am not very familar with for loops so I do not know what I should do..

Answer (score 1):

To find intersection of 2 sorted arrays, follow the below approach :

1) Use two index variables i and j, initial values with 0
2) If array1 is smaller than array2 then increment i.
3) If array1 is greater than array2 then increment j.
4) If both are same then print any of them and increment both i and j.

check this link for more information

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/

```
public class FindIntersection {

static void findInterSection(int array1[], int array2[], int array1NoOfElements, int 
array2NoOfElements) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < array1NoOfElements && j < array2NoOfElements) {
        if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {                 
            i++;
        } else if (array2[j] < array1[i]) {          
            j++;
        }
        // if both array elements are same
        else {
            System.out.println(array2[j++] + " ");
            i++;                 
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int myFirstArray[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 5 };
    int mySecondArray[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
    int m = myFirstArray.length;
    int n = mySecondArray.length;

    findInterSection(myFirstArray, mySecondArray, m, n);
}
}
```

Comment: Note it gets tricky if there are duplicates in either list.

Answer (score 0):

Make your intersection array's size the size of the smaller of your original arrays. That way, you won't ever have to increase it's capacity.

Then you can use `Arrays.copy` to transfer your results into an appropriately sized array.

Comment: How would I go about this? If I set the length of array greater than the result, the array looks like this : {2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}. (if the length of my acc was 10)

Comment: Keep track of the number of elements. Then create a new array with that many and copy the data using `Arrays.copy`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you don't need to hard-code the size of the intersection ahead of time (which is one thing you were concerned about).

As you iterate through both arrays, you can add elements found in both sets to a StringBuilder (along with some delimiter, I used a comma in the example below). Once you're finished, you can call `toString()` & then `split()` using the delimiter afterwards to get a String[]. At that point, you can put convert those String objects to int primitives & return an int[].

```
public class Scratch {

public static void main(String[] s) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] b = {2, 3, 4};
    int[] intersection = findIntersection(a, b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intersection));
}

public static int[] findIntersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
    StringBuilder intersectionStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
            if (a[j] == b[k])
                intersectionStringBuilder.append(a[j] + ",");
        }
    }
    String[] intersectionStringArray = intersectionStringBuilder.toString().split(",");
    int[] intersection = new int[intersectionStringArray.length];
    for (int current = 0; current < intersectionStringArray.length; current++) {
        intersection[current] = Integer.parseInt(intersectionStringArray[current]);
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
        if(arr1[i]==arr2[j] && !index.contains(j)){
            list.add(arr1[i]);
            index.add(j);
            break;
        }
        
    }
}

int result[]=new int[list.size()];
int k=0;
for(int i:list){
    result[k]=i;
    k++;
}


 for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
     System.out.println(result[i]); 
 }
       
    return result;
}
```