# Given two words, return a list of letters that occur in both words - Java

Tags: java, words

I have another challenge, it is when the user inputs 2 words, java prints to the console a list of letters that occur in both words. My thought was to create a char array out of the two inputs. But when I did that, I realized that some words are longer than others (Obviously), so I used an if statement to account for both possibilities (word one is bigger than word 2 and vice versa). When I did that, I got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I do not know how else to do this. I have looked on StackOverflow for other solutions. Please help! My method for the challenge is below. PS: This is a challenge "within a challenge", I have to have the user choose 1 of five programs. When the user chooses 3, it runs the program below.

```
System.out.println("Enter a String");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter another String");
    String word2 = scan.nextLine();
    String list = "";
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    char[] word1Chars = word1.toCharArray();
    char[] word2Chars = word2.toCharArray();
    if(word1Chars.length > word2Chars.length) {
        for(int s = 1; s < word1Chars.length;) {
            if(word1Chars[s] == word2Chars[s]) {
                list = "" + word1Chars[s];
            }
        }
    } else if(word2Chars.length > word2Chars.length) {
        for(int s = 1; s < word2Chars.length;) {
            if(word1Chars[s] == word2Chars[s]) {
                list = "" + word2Chars[s];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    return list;
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays) should be a good starting point. You can convert your `String`s to `char[]`s and then use the answers there.

Comment: @Dylan Black can u give a sample input and output

Comment: @JishnuPrathap an example would be if the user put in hello and yellow, the console would output e, l, and o because those chars occur in both words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this isn't supposed to be very fast, I recommend writing as little code as possible, e.g. given String word1, word2:

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( word1.split( "" ) ) );
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( word2.split( "" ) ) );
s1.retainAll( s2 );
for( String c: s1 ) System.out.print(c);
System.out.println();
```

Replace the code after the initialisation of word1 and word2.

Comment: Thanks, but where in my code would that go? My code is above

Comment: Nevermind! I put it in my code and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, I thought it wouldn't be hard to spot the right spot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex could do the trick :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "abcd";
        String s2 = "saxydp";
        System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("[^+" + s2 + "]", "").replaceAll("(\\w).*?\\1+","$1"));    
}
```

O/P :

```
ad
```

Explanation : first of all in `s1` replace everything that doesn't occur in `s2`. Next, replace every duplicate element :). Purely experimental code ..

Comment: Hey, what if s1 contains "abcdabcd"?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(word1Chars.length > word2Chars.length) {
    for(int s = 1; s < word1Chars.length;) {
```

is incrementing until s is the length of the LONGER of the two strings, but calling this:

```
if(word1Chars[s] == word2Chars[s])
```

So if word1 has 10 letters, eventually s will equal 9, and you'll check word2Chars[9], which could be out of bounds.

Comment: Ok, that explains it, but what should I do to fix it? I'm trying to stay as basic  as possible, Thanks for answering!

Comment: You could use nested for loops: for every letter l1 in word1; for every letter l2 in word2, if l1 == l2, add it to the list.  What you're doing is stepping through each word at the same time. So if it's like "h e l l o" and "h i" you're checking h==h, e==i, and stopping there.  What you want to do is h == h, h == i; THEN e == h, e == i; l == h, l == i, etc.  You probably need to do way more comparisons than you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter 2 strings : ");
String word1 = input.next();
String word2 = input.next();
String commonChar="";
for(char ch: word1.toCharArray()) {
    if(word2.contains(ch+"") && !commonChar.contains(ch+"")) {
        commonChar+=ch;
    }
}
System.out.println(commonChar);
```

o/p

```
Enter 2 strings : 
12345678
111222
12
```

In this we check if the letters contains in the other word then we add it but we add it only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use nested for loops to iterate through the char arrays and compare each individual char.  Then add to your list as needed.

Something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < word1chars.length; i++)
for(int x=0; x < word2chars.length; x++)
    if (word1chars[i] == word2chars[x])
    {
        //add your letter to your list here
    }
```

Comment: You would also have to check for duplicates in your list if you don't want the same letter to print more than once

Answer (score 0):

Using a set you can maybe achieve better performance. It follows an example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String w1 = "samefoo";
        String w2 = "barsame";

        Set set = new HashSet();

        char[] a1 = w1.toCharArray();
        char[] a2 = w2.toCharArray();
        List list = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
            set.add(a1[i]);

        for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++)
            if(set.contains(a2[i]))
                list.add(a2[i]);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not as good as some of the others, but since I've written it, may as well add it to the list.

`char[] word1Chars = word1.toCharArray();
    char[] word2Chars = word2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(word1Chars);
    Arrays.sort(word2Chars);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    String duplicates = "";
    while (i < word1Chars.length && j < word2Chars.length)
    {
        if (word1Chars[i] == word2Chars[j]) {
            duplicates += word1Chars[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (word1Chars[i] > word2Chars[j]) j++;
        else i++;
    }
    System.out.println(duplicates);`