# Java matching arrays

Tags: java, arrays

The method  which takes two integer arrays.  The method returns an integer array containing all the elements in array int[]a that are also present in array int[]b in their original sequential order in int[]a.

This is what it should output :

```
input: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 2, 10}, {3, 2, 7, 12, 3, 9, 5, 2}

output: {2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 9, 2}



input: {4, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 3, 1}, {8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4}

output: {4, 1, 9, 2, 1}
```

I tried something like this just to test it out to get my head around it but I still couldn't.

```
    public static void arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
                if (s2[j] == s1[i]) {
                    storage.add(s2[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(storage);

    }
```

Test cases:

```
int [] m1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 2, 10};
int [] m2 = {3, 2, 7, 12, 3, 9, 5, 2};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysMatching(m1, m2)));
Should print out [2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 9, 2]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the intersection of two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays)

Comment: Ill edit my question

Comment: I feel its not the same

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How does the actual behaviour differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: I get an error on this line System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysMatching(m1, m2))); saying that its not applicable for the type void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to [Codors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43041887/3992939), have the method return `int[]`:

```
public static int[] arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {

    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<>();
    //for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
    //wrong. change <= to  < or better:
    for (int i : s1) {

        //for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
        //wrong. change <= to  < or better:
        for (int j : s2) {
            if (j == i) {
                storage.add(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //if you can use streams do
    //return  storage.stream().mapToInt(i->(int)i).toArray();

    //alternatively
    int[] returnArray = new int[storage.size()];
    for(int i=0; i< storage.size(); i++) {
        returnArray[i]=storage.get(i);
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

So you can use it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysMatching(m1, m2)));`

Comment: This seems to be working but I have never learnt about mapToInt is there an alternative to that ?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the second `break` statement terminates the outer loop too early; furthermore, the indexing goes one step too far in both loop termination conditions. Change the implementation as follows.

```
public static void arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s2[j] == s1[i]) {
                storage.add(s2[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(storage);
}
```

*Edit:*

If the result is not to be printed but to be returned, the signature and the body have to be changed as follows.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s2[j] == s1[i]) {
                storage.add(s2[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return storage;
}
```

*Edit*:

If the return type is required to be `Integer[]`, the implementation has to be changed as follows.

```
public static Integer[] arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s2[j] == s1[i]) {
                storage.add(s2[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[storage.size()];
    result = storage.toArray(result);
    return result;
}
```

*Edit*:

If the return type is required to be `int[]` and no 'fancy stuff' for result conversion is desired, the code has to be changed as follows.

```
public static int[] arraysMatching(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
    ArrayList<int> storage = new ArrayList<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s2[j] == s1[i]) {
                storage.add(s2[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[storage.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < storage.length(); k++) {
        result[k] = storage.get(k);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hold on sorry I forgot to add the testcases

Comment: Please take a look at my edited post It somehow gives me an error when i print this line out System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysMatching(m1, m2)));

Comment: `arraysMatching` does not return anything so you can't print it

Comment: Gives an error with my test case. The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: This is most probably because `1`, which is the first element in the first argument, does not occur in the second argument; due to the second `break` statement, the result does not get added anything.

Comment: So should there be another array created ?

Comment: Yes, but this was already the case in the code in the initial question.

Comment: still getting this error after your suggestion The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there an error message? Is the output not as expected?

Comment: It gives me an error regarding the System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysMatching(m1, m2))); line and wont even let me print. The answer below lets me print but havn't learnt about mapToInt before